# How can I see function doc or parameter info when CTRL+P is print

Tags: webstorm

In the docs for WebStorm it says <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> is to see parameter into but when I try Ctrl+P it launches the Print Dialog.

<kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> is supposed to let me see the doc of a function but when I try it, the cursor jumps around in the document. I don't know what it's doing but its not showing any doc.

I am using Windows -- how can I see parameter info or the function's comment/doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are correct shortcuts if you are using Default keymap. In your case you are using incompatible one.

1. You can change and customize your keymap at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`.
2. If you want to see what keys those 2 actions have in current keymap -- just look for them in `View` menu (`Parameter Info` and `Quick Documentation` actions).

Comment: I was using Eclipse key mappings. changed it to default and the keymappings match the documentation now. thanks